# Phpmyadmin and Apache 2.4 - 404 errors

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

Has anyone had problems with 404 errors and phpmyadmin after upgrading to Apache 2.4?

My ubuntu machine ran the upgrade a few days ago and I have not been able to access localhost/phpmyadmin since.  I just get 404 errors.

I know there have been security changes in 2.4 but I checked out the settings in the phpmyadmin.conf loaded by apache and I can't see anything that would affect non-admin users.  Furthermore I commented out the old security rules and added the new ones, but still not working...

Comment: Check if your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default file has got changed in Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer with a bit of fiddling.

Basically /phpmyadmin is an alias for /usr/share/phpmyadmin  This was previously defined in phpmyadmin.conf.  I now have it defined in the apache2 alias.conf file, and it works fine.

Not sure if that means that I am missing out on other things defined in phpmyadmin.conf, but will have to see, I suppose.

Answer (score 15):

the directory of configuration files apparently changed in apahe 2.4 fron conf.d to conf-available. Also, the conf files must be loaded explicitly. I did

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/

sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin 

sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Worked for me. After sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin I also have to comment the line 31 'Require valid-user' from /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf

Comment: I think it's `sudo service apache2 restart` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I found.

The configuration file is `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`.

The package installer for phpMyAdmin creates a link from `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf` to the configuration file.

In my case, Apache did not seem to be picking up that configuration. So I created a link in my "sites-available" folder and enabled the site:

```
ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf

a2ensite phpmyadmin
```

Seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Apache update probably overwrites config.

Adding `include conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf` to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected your httpd server, during the installatino process. I thought I had checked apache, but I didnot.

I removed phpmyadmin and reinstall it taking care to check apache this time, and everything was automatically setted up. I was finally able to use phpmyadmin without configure anything else.